# Unremovable php error at Wordpress White Screen of Death

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

I know there are a lot of White Screen of Death pages, but I can't seem to wrap my head around this one.

On my site (http://www.wavo.be), I get a Whitescreen of Death. I renamed the plugins folder and the custom theme folder.. some errors dissapeared but this one stayed:

> Notice: Undefined index: rfd1b0e6b in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/109379/webspace/httpdocs/wp-includes/locale.php on line 1

Any ideas where I should look?
I presume the site updated itself and then the errors occured..

Comment: re-install your wordpress (wp-admin and wp-includes folders) and try it again and please take a look into your PHP errorlog and post the messages.

Comment: white screen of death = php errors off, turn them on to see why you are getting the screen.

Comment: re-installed and everything was back up again. But today it stopped working again! I've disabled all automatic updates.. and still, another error (something completely different this time). How is that possible? "Warning: require_once(/usr/local/pem/vhosts/109379/webspace/httpdocs/wp-includes/wp-db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/pem/vhosts/109379/webspace/httpdocs/wp-includes/load.php on line 345 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/usr/local/pem/vhosts/109379/webspace/httpdocs/wp-includes/wp-db.php' (include_path='.:/php/includes') in ..